# $(...).DataTable(...).fnAddData is not a function

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have an error in the console which says that `fnAddData is not a function`, but my application works.

Just before, I had the error `fnClearTable is not a function` so I searched and I replaced it by just clear() so the error was gone. But now there's this error with `fnAddData`.

I searched and didn't find, it seems to be an uncommon error.

Here's where I use the `fnAddData`:

```
var newRow = $('#tabBrouillon').DataTable().fnAddData([
    dataTab[i+3],
    dataTab[i+4],
    dataTab[i+5],
    dataTab[i+6],
    img,
])
```

Is there a function which can replace this one or something to solve this error ?

Thank you

Comment: What version of DataTable are you using?

Comment: I'm using DataTable 1.10.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the capital letter `D` in `DataTable()` function.

Just change it to `dataTable()`.

```js
$('#tabBrouillon').dataTable().fnAddData([
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4,
  5,
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table id="tabBrouillon" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: At the beginning I had dataTable instead of DataTable but I had the problem with fnClearTable and I saw that the error could be due to the d in lowercase. When I replace DataTable by dataTable I have the error $(...).dataTable(...).clear is not a function.

Comment: Haha, apparently you have to choose one version. Or you could use both. One in case when you need to add and second when you want to clear. Just don't save to a variable but initiate it every time. That's the best solution I can think of.

Comment: Ok then x) I'm going to try that. Thank you !

Comment: Using DataTable() for init, and dataTable().fnNAME worked today.